# How to create new instances of both models contributing in OneToOne relationship in django rest framework (DRF)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created an `Author` model in which it has a `OneToOne` relationship with default Django User, as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='author',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default="",
    )

    is_author = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )
```

And here I have created the following viewset:

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
    queryset = Author.objects.all()

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list" or self.action == "retrieve" or self.action == "update":
            self.permission_classes = [IsCurrentOwner, permissions.IsAdminUser]

        elif self.action == "create":
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

        return super(AuthorViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

**Question** Is there any way that I can create both `user` and `author` in one step (request)? How?

serializer code:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = "__all__"

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'id': {'read_only': True}
        }
```

I have tried the following request but it doesn't work.

```
#url: localhost:8000/users/
#method: POST

{
    "user": {
        "username": "mostafa",
        "password": "1"
    }       
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "user": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you will need to create another serializer for user:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
```

After that, make the user field in your `AuthorSerializer` an instance of `UserSerializer` and override the create method in this manner:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = "__all__"

        extra_kwargs = {
            'id': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = None
        if "user" in validated_data:
            user_data = validated_data.pop("user") or {}
            user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data) # Assuming that it is default django user model
        author = Author.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        author.save()
        return author
```

curl script for your request payload:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "user": {
        "username": "mostafa",
        "password": "abcd"
    },
    "is_author": true
}'
```

And it responses as below:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "last_login": null,
        "is_superuser": false,
        "username": "mostafa",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "email": "",
        "is_staff": false,
        "is_active": true,
        "date_joined": "2020-12-05T09:54:37.674749Z",
        "groups": [],
        "user_permissions": []
    },
    "is_author": true
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the sample request to create a new user and author?

Comment: The create user here is just a dummy part. I wasn't sure if you are using the default User model or not. If you are using the default model then I will be updating the answer here.

Comment: Do you have any idea for [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156787/different-queryset-based-on-permissions-in-django-rest-framework)?